# Http Request in Qgis3 Plugin

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I need to do some HTTP request based on feature in PyQGIS.

Based on http://zetcode.com/pyqt/qnetworkaccessmanager/ I created this class:

```
from typing import Callable

from PyQt5.QtNetwork import  QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog


class HttpGetPhoto:
    photo_id: str = None
    callback: Callable = None

    def __init__(self, photo_id: str, handleResponseCallback: Callable):
        self.photo_id = photo_id
        self.callback = handleResponseCallback

    def doRequest(self):
        url = f'https://example.net/photos/{self.photo_id}.jpg'
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(f'Making a request to {url}')
        req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))

        self.nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nam.finished.connect(self.handleResponse)
        self.nam.get(req)

    def handleResponse(self, reply) -> None:
        #er = reply.error() -> treat error :
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(f'Err ? {reply.error()}. Reply message : {reply}')
        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.loadFromData(reply.readAll()) 
        self.callback(img)
```

I get the "Making a request to https://example.net/photos/XXX.jpg but I never get the response. am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. When calling `HttpGetPhoto().doRequest()` I was not doing anythign with the object after word, so the the Gc deleted it. Simple :-/